# Ubuntu doesn't detect wifi-reset network scripts

Tags: networking

I am a new user of Ubuntu. Recently I was trying to set up an infrastructure hotspot in Ubuntu to connect my Android to the eth connection, following some answers given in this forum. However it did not succeed, and when I booted my system, the eth connection wasn't working, along with no wifi recognition. I deleted the eth connection, that must have reset the eth connection and it started working again. However although my wifi is on, it doesn't detect any signal. It shows wireless network and below it `device not managed`.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

To set up a simple wifi hotpsot for an Android phone use `ap-hotspot` as detailed [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/06/how-to-set-up-wireless-hotspot-access.html). 
 It works for me ;-)

Basically, install it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ap-hotspot
```

<sup>[Use `ppa`'s at your own risk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out-fo)</sup>
Start it with:

```
sudo ap-hotspot start
```

You can also stop it:

```
sudo ap-hotspot stop
```

and configure it:

```
sudo ap-hotspot configure
```

Android does not seem to support the hotspot created in Ubuntu - <sub><rant>even though I have never had this trouble with [another operating system](http://fedoraproject.org/)</rant></sub>

Ubuntu 14.04 apparently needs a special fix as well (bear in mind it does not have the security fixes in the newer versions).

> #### For Ubuntu 14.04:
>
> also the `hostapd` version in Ubuntu 14.04 is buggy and doesn't
>   work properly. To get AP-Hotspot to work with hostapd in Ubuntu 14.04,
>   you need to downgrade hostapd and use apt to hold the package so it's
>   not upgraded (thanks to spupuz for the tip!). To do this, use the
>   following commands:
>
> **64bit:**
>
> ```
> cd /tmp
> wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/wpa/hostapd_1.0-3ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb
> sudo dpkg -i hostapd*.deb
> sudo apt-mark hold hostapd
> ```
>
> **32bit:**
>
> ```
> cd /tmp
> wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/wpa/hostapd_1.0-3ubuntu2.1_i386.deb
> sudo dpkg -i hostapd*.deb
> sudo apt-mark hold hostapd
> ```